# Can any body help me out with the code for making a panel with check boxes inside a combo box in extjs 4.2

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

i want check boxes inside a combo box in extjs 4.2 i have tried the below code but it is not working may be i am not able to make it work but it   is using  images to show check and uncheck functionality. can some help me out ?

```
function stackoverflow() {
Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Select multiple names ',
    id: 'BCCAddress',
    name: 'BCCAddress',
    maxHeight: 150,        
    width: 500,
    multiSelect: true,
    emptyText : "Select Bcc email addresses",
    renderTo: 'fi-form',
    //store: myArrayStore,
    store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        fields: ['name'],
        data : myArrayStore  
    }),

    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'name',
    forceSelection: false,
    editable: false,
    mode: 'MULTI',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    listConfig : {          
        getInnerTpl : function() {
            return '<div class="x-combo-list-item"><img src="' + Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL + '" class="chkCombo-default-icon chkCombo" /> {fieldName} </div>';
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: I also think that checkboxes inside a combobox are a bad idea. What would you use it for ? Only to visually distinguish the selected items ? Or is there another use ?

Comment: it is client requirement so cant help out with it @LorenzMeyer

Comment: If you develop merely to the letter what the client asks for, you are just a mere developper. But when the client comes up with a solution to his problem that falls short, you should come up with a better solution that convinces the client. This makes you an outstanding developper.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer actually the below code is also not working.
i want to make a drop down in which there will be check boxes based on the number of quaters in 6 years. we have to populate check boxes  in rows and columns , i will be glad if you can help me with this.

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear at all what you want to do. I newer saw anywhere a dropdown with checkboxes in it. I cannot immagine what you want to achieve, sounds like a calf with wings... Maybe I will understand with a picture ?

Comment: yes same here i didnt saw it myself . i was able to display multiple checkboxes in drop down . I dont have enough stars to post a pic @LorenzMeyer 1. i want a drop down. 2. i want data with check boxes in column wise and row wise
[]data1 []data2 []data3
[]data4 []data5 []data6

i want above data in combo box in same manner.
i think now picture is more clear to you.

Comment: And you want to be able to check the boxes ?! That will not be possible because in a combobox a click will select the line.

Comment: Also a combobox is a text field with a flyout button. Displaying a checkbox inside a textfield is impossible.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer  Hey Pal, i gave wings to calf i inserted grid in combo box

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's a bad idea, sencha don't like when changing standard behaviour. But it's simply "kludge". Your code does not have correct css style. Look at this:

```
var data = [
    [1, 'Ext.Js'],
    [2, 'Angular.js'],
    [3, 'Ember.js'],
    [4, 'Олю']
];

// in real solution add it to your css file
var customStyle = ".x-boundlist-item img.chkCombo { width: 13px; height: 13px; background: transparent url('https://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-4.0.7-gpl/resources/themes/images/default/form/checkbox.gif'); }" + ".x-boundlist-selected img.chkCombo { background-position: 0 -13px; width: 13px; height: 13px; background: transparent url(https://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-4.0.7-gpl/resources/themes/images/default/form/checkbox.gif'); }";

Ext.util.CSS.createStyleSheet(customStyle);


Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'I like',
    id: 'BCCAddress',
    name: 'BCCAddress',
    maxHeight: 150,
    width: 500,
    multiSelect: true,
    emptyText: "",
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

    store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        id: 0,
        fields: ['Id', 'Name'],
        data: data
    }),

    displayField: 'Name',
    valueField: 'Id',
    forceSelection: false,
    editable: false,
    mode: 'local',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    listConfig: {
        getInnerTpl: function() {
            return '<div class="x-combo-list-item"><img src="' + Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL + '" class="chkCombo-default-icon chkCombo" /> {Name} </div>';
        }
    }
});
```

---

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/hd3)

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes in a combobox is impossible.
Period.

Think about it differently, and you will find a solution.

You say you need checkboxes above. So that's the way to go. Put your checkboxes in a row. Then you add a button that when clicked opens a window with a grid in it that contains the other checkboxes.

This will look and behave like what you describe.

Conclusion:
**You have to change your approach.** A framework offers bricks that you put together to get what you want. Like LEGO. If you take the right brickes you can achieve great things in a few time.

Currently, you immagine bricks that don't exist, and try to force something to work that impossible way that you immagined. Why would you use a framework then ? Your free to invent the impossible, even flying calves or a snake with seven heads.